# If $m > 3$, then $m^2 - 4$ is not prime

Tags: proof-writing, prime-numbers

I am trying to create a proof that for all integers $m$, if $m > 3$, then $m^2-4$ is not prime. I am having issue however actually figuring out how to finish it off. Here's what I have so far...

Proof: Let integer m be given. $m^2 - 4 = (m-2)(m+2)$. Suppose that $m > 3$. Since $m > 3$, $m+2 > m-2 > 1$...

Most of the examples that I have create an integer $k$ and use it to finish the proof but I'm not sure how to define it in this example. Any help would be wonderful! Thanks.

Comment: $m^2-4$ can be factored!

Comment: And that gives me (m+2)(m-2). Would i set my k equal to that?

Comment: Since $m>3$, $m+2>m-2>1$, a prime can' t be a product of two integers both greater than 1.

Comment: Alright almost got it down but where did the 1 come from? I get that m+2 > m-2. Why the 1 though?

Comment: $m>3=2+1\implies m-2>1$

Comment: Okay I think I got it Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Hint:

$$
m^2 - 4 = (m - 2)(m + 2)
$$